# Is it possible to expose the "Items to Approve" on Salesforce Mobile App?

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, approval-process, salesforce-sdk-android, spring22

I found out that `Items to Approve` is only on Classic Experience on Salesforce :

[image: Classic Experience View]

Is there a way to expose `Items to Approve` in Salesforce Mobile app (I'm using iOS) too?

[image: Salesforce Mobile app]

Right now, the only way I can approve stuff is go to the bell notification and approve the Opportunity one by one. I need the `Item to Approve` so I can see all the Opportunities to approve in **one go**. Can this be done or is this a Salesforce limitation?

List of devices I want this to be shown on :

1. iPhones
2. Android Phones
3. Tablets (iOS and Android)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce1 app - Approval tab is missing on mobile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60611/salesforce1-app-approval-tab-is-missing-on-mobile)

Comment: Recommend reviewing [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVtIUAV/ability-to-customize-the-columns-in-the-items-to-approve-section-on-home-page) and [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lex_gaps_limitations_process_automation.htm&type=5)

Comment: @GuyClairbois Interesting I need to explore if this can really work on mobile. Note what I want is to be able to approve multiple in one go. Not sure if that solution can do that

Comment: @Swetha Thanks for linking idea. What I got are 2 free apps to try https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYuuXUAT (Forcelution apps)
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5DmREAV ( Salesforce lab)